# How do i archive newly added DB backups?

Tags: windows, backup, sql-server-2005, maintenance, archive

I'm using Windows Server 2003, Sql-Server 2005 and 7-zip for archiving.

Each day maintenance plan adds all DBs to backup and i need to archive those but just those files.

How do i create .bat or .vbs script which

1. deletes previous archive
2. adds only new (of this day) files to archive, while naming this archive 1sql_020810.7z (date)

I don't need help with 7-zip commands but with dos/vbs. I don't know how to get Current Date and Files of This Day to archive...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in you sql server maintenance plan, you can delete the previous backup (however, it won't know anything about your archive)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%I in (currentarc.txt) do call :prune %%I
goto :renbackup

:prune
del %1


:renbackup
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set date=%%a-%%b-%%c)

move d:\backup\dbbackup.bak c:\backup\dbbackup%date%.bak
echo dbbackup%date%.bak > currentarc.txt
7z .....  (do your 7zip stuff on the file)
```

the first part of this batch file deletes the past archive

the second part of the batch file renames the current backup from sql server to one that has a date and adds the file name to a file that you will need the next time.  then you can do your compression with 7zip.

note that i didn't test this but the concept should work.